# check and remove a particular string from nsmutable array without index

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring, nsmutablearray

In Xcode, I store some `NSString` in `NSMutableArray`.

```
Hello
Here
MyBook
Bible
Array
Name2
There
IamCriminal
```

User can enter string.

```
Name2
```

I need to delete that particular string from `NSMutableArray` without knowing index of the string. I have some idea that, Use iteration. Any other Best way. Plz Give with sample codings.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can use `containsObject` method in an `NSMutableArray`

```
if ([yourArray containsObject:@"object"]) {
    [yourArray removeObject:@"object"];
}
```

**Swift:**

```
if yourArray.contains("object") {
    yourArray = yourArray.filter{ $0 != "object" } 
}
```

Comment: I dont think this is going to work. Here this method will check the reference not the content.

Comment: it's working because you are taking constant string. Insert this `NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:"hello"];` in array and then use your method to remove `@"hello"`

Comment: You would think that you are comparing the pointer address of 2 strings but it does actually compare the strings:P

Comment: can not work as you have two instances by creating @object" ... different memory objects

Answer (score 8):

```
[array removeObject:@"Name2"];
```

The documentation for NSMutableArray’s removeObject: method states:

> matches are determined on the basis of an object’s response to the
>   isEqual: message

In other words, this method iterates over your array comparing the objects to `@"Name2"`. If an object is equal to `@"Name2"`, it is removed from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
BOOL flag = [arrayName containsObject:Str];   

if (flag == YES)
{   
     [arrayName removeObject:Str];
}
```

Comment: I dont think this is going to work. Here this method will check the reference not the content.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore i have already implemented in code & its working.

Comment: Pelase read the question carefully. And I have commented @arthan.v answer. please go through that.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore See enderstocker's answer (and the documentation)

Answer (score 0):

```
[array removeObject:@"name2"];
```

Comment: I dont think this is going to work. Here this method will check the reference not the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
for(NSString *string in array)
{
    if([[string lowercasestring] isEqualToSring:[yourString lowercasestring]])
    {
        [array removeObject:string];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: He's asking a solution except the traditional stuff that you have written

Answer (score 0):

YOu can simply use

```
[yourArray removeObject:stringObjectToDelete];
```

This method uses indexOfObject: to locate matches and then removes them by using removeObjectAtIndex:. Thus, matches are determined on the basis of an object’s response to the isEqual: message. If the array does not contain anObject, the method has no effect.